# why browser auto add to link string in end when I insert it in html

Tags: javascript, angular8, wijmo

I use grapecity pdf viewer

```
wj-pdf-viewer #pdfViewer 
  [serviceUrl]="'https://test.....azurewebsites.net/'"
  [filePath]="'books/%D7%9B%D7%A4.......pdf'">
</wj-pdf-viewer>
```

and in network tab I see that it added to result string something 
https://test....azurewebsites.net/books/%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%9C-%D7%95%D....pdf/$pdf?_=1571151136434

that is why I got 404 error

How I have to correct set link to pdf?
how to avoid auto adding string at the end of link

Thanks!

Comment: If you are referring to the `?_=1571151136434` that is a cache busting technique that appends the current time millisecond to the end so that you always get fresh data and not from cache. But, without more details I can't tell you who adds id, maybe jQuery, maybe some other javascript framework you use.

Comment: yes, and that is why it is different link 
because it added as 'testdomain.com/pdf_file.pdf/$PDF?_=123456'
it add slash at the end of link string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wijmo's PDF viewer is only compatible with C1WebApi PDF services and from what I understand, you have hosted your PDF document elsewhere. To learn more about C1WebApi, refer to this [link](https://www.grapecity.com/webapi).